# How Can i send the Message or Notification to Particular Friend In Facebook

Tags: android, ios, facebook, wcf, facebook-graph-api

I need to send the Notification or Message to Particular Friend In Facebook,
I have used the WCF Webservice and i also get the Friend's ID but when i send the message or Notification then I m getting the Following Error AS 
"(OAuthException - #200) (#200) Feed story publishing to other users is disabled for this application"

Please reply me ASAP
Thanks in Advance !!!

Nikunj

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can't send private messages any more through the graph-api due to some abuse issues. If you're just trying to post to someone's news feed then you need to be sure that you request the appropriate permissions when generating your access token (either publish_stream or publish_actions depending on what exactly you're trying). The permissions are listed here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

Details for requesting additional permissions in the android SDK are here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/#step3

Hope this helps.

Edit:

Re Email, there is no way to get a friend's email. The "email" permission gives you access to the user's email, but there is no equivalent for "friends_email". Facebook is pretty wary about giving apps the ability to privately contact people for fear of spam. Sorry.

Comment: Can we get facebook friend email from facebook id ?
please send if any solution is there?

Comment: Facebook does not allow this, no.

Another answer covers this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797874/how-can-i-get-facebook-friends-list-email-addresses