# Facebook API - getting friend list with detail info again

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm using Facebook SDK ( http://facebooksdk.net )  and want to get friend list with the following information:
1. ID
2. Name
3. Photo
4. link
5. Email
6. etc...

I have read Facebook's documentation and different posts of forum (including stackoverflow), but I'm confused. After it I'm not sure, is it possible to get this information by API request or not. First at all, this request returns only ID and name data:

```
        var client = new FacebookClient("XXX");
        dynamic friends = client.Get("/me/friends");
```

Next step - try to modify this request to specify returned fields:

```
        var client = new FacebookClient("XXX");
        dynamic friends = client.Get("/me/friends?fields=about,bio,age_range,first_name,gender,address,email,location,link,languages,username,last_name,timezone,updated_time");
```

it returns only some fields:

```
  "first_name": "XXX", 
  "gender": "male", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/XXX", 
  "username": "XXX", 
  "last_name": "XXX", 
  "updated_time": "2013-09-07T12:18:34+0000", 
  "id": "XXX"
```

is it possible to return more fields? As I understood, it depends on permissions. I try to set these permissions. I go to Applications -> MyApp -> Permissions, and see, that field "User & Friend Permissions" is empty. I try to set some permissions, i.e.

```
user_about_me,friends_about_me
```

and after click "Save" button I see the message:

> Changes saved. Note that your changes may take several minutes to
>   propagate to all servers.

but field "User & Friend Permissions" is empty again. First question : why and how can I see all set permissions?

secondly - I don't see any changes in my request via FacebookClient (but field "About" is added to request). Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields that you can get without any extra permissions:

1. first_name
2. gender
3. link
4. username
5. last_name
6. updated_time
7. id

With permissions-

`friends_about_me` - about, bio

`friends_location` - location

`friends_likes` - languages

Invalid fields (I don't know from where you saw these)-

1. age_range
2. address
3. email
4. timezone

---

Another thing that you are not getting all the fields is because the permissions are not being asked by the user (and hence not granted any to your app).

This is because, you have to add the permissions in your code, while login-in the user- not just adding permissions in the App Settings.

For eg, if you are using javascript sdk, it is done using the **scope** parameter. [Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/)

---

You can always test your call here: [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Comment: I found age_range, address, email. timezone here - http://www.magicscreenshot.com/ResizeImage/DTS0C0dYLUE.jpg

Comment: I did call for get permissions of user and see, that user has permission "friends_about_me":1, but when I add this field to get user detail info - I don't see this field...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, you can see the answer [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#checking), use the Facebook graph api and search /{user id}/permissions.

Some clerification for the rest. You can't get friends email address as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797874/how-can-i-get-facebook-friends-list-email-addresses). In order to get the friends profile picture you need to add the field *picture* (you can specify the size like this *picture.width().height(*).

I reccomend you try to use [Facebooks Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to play with the permissions and the info you request.

Comment: I confused again. So, permissions can be set by user and inside application? Where user can set permissions? Why permissions of application are necessary?